Compiling GLAD with Clang and -pedantic flag on Windows
When compiling GLAD with Clang using these flags: -pedantic -Wall -Wextra I get these warnings:
C:/Dev/glad/include\KHR/khrplatform.h:189:9: warning: extension used [-Wlanguage-extension-token]
  189 | typedef __int32                 khronos_int32_t;
      |         ^
C:/Dev/glad/include\KHR/khrplatform.h:190:18: warning: extension used [-Wlanguage-extension-token]
  190 | typedef unsigned __int32        khronos_uint32_t;
      |                  ^
C:/Dev/glad/include\KHR/khrplatform.h:191:9: warning: extension used [-Wlanguage-extension-token]
  191 | typedef __int64                 khronos_int64_t;
      |         ^
C:/Dev/glad/include\KHR/khrplatform.h:192:18: warning: extension used [-Wlanguage-extension-token]
  192 | typedef unsigned __int64        khronos_uint64_t;
      |         

These warnings do not happen on Linux.
This seems to be the piece of code where the warning is generated:
#elif defined(_WIN32) && !defined(__SCITECH_SNAP__)

/*
 * Win32
 */
typedef __int32                 khronos_int32_t;
typedef unsigned __int32        khronos_uint32_t;
typedef __int64                 khronos_int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64        khronos_uint64_t;
#define KHRONOS_SUPPORT_INT64   1
#define KHRONOS_SUPPORT_FLOAT   1

Which is only used if _WIN32 is defined, it uses __intN types that are not standard.
Above this chunk of code is another block that looks like this:
#if (defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L) || defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__SCO__) || defined(__USLC__)


/*
 * Using <stdint.h>
 */
#include <stdint.h>
typedef int32_t                 khronos_int32_t;
typedef uint32_t                khronos_uint32_t;
typedef int64_t                 khronos_int64_t;
typedef uint64_t                khronos_uint64_t;
#define KHRONOS_SUPPORT_INT64   1
#define KHRONOS_SUPPORT_FLOAT   1

...and this one seems to use the standard integer types.
My Question:
Is there a way to compile with pedantic without having these warnings generated?
For example is there a way to force the second block of code to be used instead so that GLAD won't use platform-specific extensions?
Why does GLAD use these non-standard types in the first place?
Reproduction Steps:

Generate GLAD from here

Copy the src and include directories to the root of your project

Create a main.cpp in the root of the project

Add this code to main.cpp
#include <glad/glad.h>
int main() {}


run this command:
clang++ .\src\glad.c .\main.cpp -I .\include\ -pedantic



This will cause the warnings mentioned above.

Report a bug to Glad, and for now work around this by temporarily disabling this warning with #pragmas.

-Wno-language-extension-token may also be an option for the time being.

@3CxEZiVlQ created github issue here hope that helps you replicate

What is .\src and .\include? If .\include is C:/Dev/glad/include then -I .\include is a mistake. Search of paths that are not owned by your project should be set like -isystem ./include.

@3CxEZiVlQ oh I just created a directory called "glad" to create the dummy example, so the C:\Dev\glad IS the project folder, the include and src are coppied from glad.zip, I should have called it C:\Dev\glad-test or something but it's name isn't important, unless I misunderstood what you mean?

Not sure it'd solve your issue, but since you're importing C code in C++, you should enclose the #include with extern "C" {}
